# Remove Lesser Values from List

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, for-loop

I have a text file that contains:
xxx_123
xxx_001
xxx_345
YYY_123
ZZZ_789
ZZZ_123

I want to return a list with:
xxx_345
YYY_123
ZZZ_789

```
for item in list1:
    item = item.split("_")
    part1 = item[0]
    part2 = item[1]

    for line in list1:
        line = line.split("_")
        Bpart1 = line[0]
        Bpart2 = line[1]

        if part1 == Bpart1:
            if part2>Bpart2:
                print item
        else:
            print "Items do not match"
```

any thoughts?

Comment: You are not returning list, and printed item is not equal to input item (it's splitted).

Comment: How can `part2 > part2` ever be true? Tell me any number that is greater than itself.

Comment: Whether I'm returning the list or printing the correct items, it doesn't matter- that part I can handle.

As for the part2>part2, intended to put my other part of the code which just loops again but still returns incorrect values

Comment: @Mephy: that number would be `infinity`

Answer (score 1):

You cant do it in one go, so you need to keep the results:

```
from collections import defaultdict
cache = defaultdict(int)

for item in list1:
    item = item.split("_")
    key = item[0]
    value = int(item[1])

    if cache[key] < value:
        cache[key] = value

for k, v in cache.items():
    print("{}_{}".format(k, v))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

list1 = ['xxx_123', 'xxx_001', 'xxx_345', 'YYY_123', 'ZZZ_789', 'ZZZ_123']

d = OrderedDict()

for item in list1:
    part1, part2 = item.split('_', 1)
    part2 = int(part2)

    if d.setdefault(part1, part2) < part2:
        d[part1] = part2

for key, value in d.iteritems():
    print '{}_{}'.format(key, value)

# xxx_345
# YYY_123
# ZZZ_789
```

Comment: Almost works.  It still prints everything, but when I print the d, I can see that last of that list is the correct answer, but can't extract that

Comment: @JoshClayton If your requirement is a list of string, substitute the two last lines of code with a list comprehension: `result = ['{}_{}'.format(key, value) for key, value in d.iteritems()]

Answer (score 0):

I currently have this:

```
cache = defaultdict()
for item in list1:
    item= item.split('_')
    part1 = item[0]
    part2 = int(item[1])
if cache.setdefault(part1,part2)<part2:
    cache[part1] = part2
    for part1,part2 in cache.iteritems():
        line = "%s_%s"%(part1,part2)
        print line
```